# Jenkins - "sh" splits my command and tries to execute it separatly

Tags: jenkins, sh, pipeline

I am trying to run a linux command in a jenkins pipeline using sh, but for some reason my command get's spited in 2 and tries to execute them sparely.
The result of the pipeline is:
curl --insecure -u '****:****' --upload-file ./file.ear
curl: no URL specified!
Please see the image.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('use curl'){
            steps{
                script{
                    withCredentials([
                        usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'CREDENTIALS', usernameVariable: 'USER', passwordVariable: 'PWD')
                    ]) {
                          sh(script:"curl --insecure -u ${USER}:${PWD} --upload-file ./" + Artifact + " " + REPO_URL + Artifact.substring(0, Artifact.length() - 5) + "/", returnStdout: false)
                    } //withCredentials
                } // scripts
            } //steps
        } //stage
    } 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Check if the `Artifact` variable doesn't end with a newline (especially if the value is parsed from somewhere else), you can try with `... + Artifact.trim() + ...`

Answer (score 0):

Using `Artifact.trim()` did not fix it. But using `Artrifact.substring(0, Artifact.length() - 1)` instead did the trick.